# php time checking within two day ( between today 5PM AND TOMORROW 2AM with time() )

Tags: php, date, time

I have a shop that opens at 5 PM and closes after 2 AM (which is tomorrow).

```
$opening_time = date('m-d h:i A', strtotime($user['from_time']));
$close_time = date('m-d h:i A', strtotime($user['to_time'].' + 1 days'));
$current = date('m-d h:i A',time());

$status = (time() > strtotime( $user['from_time'] ) && time() < strtotime( $user['to_time'].' + 1 days' ))?"open":"close";
```

This what i am trying to do everything works perfectly until 00:00 after that my condition fails to check if its time is after opening time

Please help me on this. This been eating my head for a week.

Comment: You mean it tells you that the shop is closed?

Comment: If you run this between midnight and 2am, `$opening_time` is 5pm that day, not the previous day, and `$close_time` is 2am tomorrow.

Comment: It's not clear what you want your code to return. State the inputs, an example couple of values and expected result.

Comment: It seems you "know" that the open time range will surely cross midnight. If that's the case, you can do `$status=time()<=$close_time) || time()>=$opening_time`.

Comment: @BurhanKhalid yes. It tells that shop is closed

Comment: @deed02392 I want print open if the time is between 5pm and 2am and closed if its not

Comment: @Passerby my opening time is 5PM and closing time is 2AM. If the current time is between that shop will be "open". If its not shop is "closed". This is my requirement

Comment: @jack Yes I understand that -- that means your available time is (all in the sense of "today") either after 5PM, or before 2AM.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your question is really confusing, but if all you need is to check if time is between 5pm and 2am this is very simple:

```
$hour = date("G", time());

echo (($hour > 16) || ($hour < 2)) ? "open" : "closed"
```

Comment: Thanks for the idea. How can i make this work for minutes also? THat means between 5.10pm  and and 2.15am

Comment: Get the minutes in another variable, change hour to 1 and check minutes up to 59 etc.

Comment: @jack you can get the minutes with `$minute = (int)date("i", time())` then check if it is within bounds